Nuance of やぶさかではない
From anime Black Lagoon, Nun who is in business of supplying overseas weapons to mafia responds to Revy's request to do as the books say and have a certain weapon in stock:

ただね別んとこの顧客がさ
早急に入り用っておっしゃってるもんでねえ
とはいえラグーンだってお得意さんだ
それを回すんだってやぶさかじゃないさね
まあ色をつけるか割引仕事ってところかねえ
It's just that another
customer... ...is saying they need it immediately.
However, as Lagoon
is a very good customer of ours...
...I wouldn't mind handing it over
to you.
Anyway, it will either have to be a better deal or a discount
on your services.

From what I can tell this やぶさかじゃない means something like "do not begrudge doing", and seems to be used in the business world a lot, but I was also able to find many examples on SNS of this being used almost casually? Perhaps as a joke? What is the nuance of this expression and how is it typically used?

The meaning is pretty much "woudn't mind [doing something]", as the translation suggests. It's a bit dated and theatrical, and not a phrase that a random child would say to a family member, though.
It looks like it means "delighted to do something" without reservation prescriptively, but I think in popular understanding it could imply some reluctance, too. (Like, "I can do that as a favor to you, although there is no practical benefit for me.")
You typically encouter the phrase in written form (if you consider lines by characters in a novel as written). A businessperson today might use it in an email, so it's not exclusively in the literary register.

+1, The link in the answer (https://www.bunka.go.jp/prmagazine/rensai/kotoba/kotoba_007.html) definitely worth reading.
